# NoSuchMethodError for RecyclerView in Espresso test

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nosuchmethoderror, android-espresso

Currently I am trying to test the views using RecyclerView. The app works great, but in the test, it doesn't, it couldn't find method of RecyclerView, the followings are the dependencies in the test file

```
androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

And I got errors when I was using RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition and it will call RecyclerView's scrollToPosition() method. But it complains that it couldn't find this method:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollToPosition
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ScrollToPositionViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:397)
at android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions$ActionOnItemAtPositionViewAction.perform(RecyclerViewActions.java:277)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
....
```

I assume the problem is, since it works fine in the app, that in the test, it might use the older version than the app. And for test dependency, the version for recyclerView is 21.0.3 and app version is 22.2.0. However, after I change the app version of RecyclerView to 21.0.3 (same as in test), it still has same error.

Much appreciate any comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after two days of searching, finally I found the solution. It has something to do with Proguard. It turns out that the RecyclerView is obfuscated by Android Proguard. Thats the reason why Espresso cannot find this method.

Just simply add

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView { *; }
```

in proguard-rules.text and then you are all set.

Comment: Even if proguard is disabled for your debug builds!